# Reducer is not called even after action is dispatched and payload is received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've created a react app using `create-react-app` and `react-redux`. I dispatch an action using `mapDispatchToProps` on clicking a button and it returns a payload. But when I try to retrieve the props using `mapStateToProps` in my component, it returns the initial state.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to debug thoroughly and I realize that the action is dispatched and the payload makes it to the action creator. But the reducer isn't triggered after the action is dispatched.

It might be how I am calling it or how I have set up my reducer as well.

**index.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/index.css';
import App from './App/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**reducers/Reducer.js**

reducers/Reducer.js

```
import { GET_RESP } from '../modules/actions'

   function getInitialState () {
     return {
       predictions: [],
       score: null
     }
   }

   function gesResp (state, payload) {
     return {
       ...state,
       predictions: payload.predictions,
       score: payload.score
     }
   }

   export function Reducer (state, action) {
     if (!state) {
       return getInitialState();
     }
     switch(action.type) {
       case GET_RESP:
         return gesResp(state, action.payload);
         default:
           return state;
     }
   }

   export default Reducer;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import Reducer from './Reducer'

   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     Reducer
   });

   export default rootReducer;
```

**action.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

   // actions:
   export const GET_RESP = 'GET_RESP';

   // action creators:
   export function gesResp (payload) {
     return {
       type: GET_RESP,
       payload: payload
     }
   }

   export function fetchRecommendations (description, resp) {
     let url = 'myendpointurl';
     let requestPayload = {
       description: description,
       resp: resp
     }
     return (dispatch) => {
       return axios.post(url, requestPayload)
         .then(function(res) {
           gesResp(res.data);
       })
     }
   }
```

**component file: (I'm only posting related code):**

```
 handleSubmit () {
       this.props.fetchMyRecommendations(Desc, 
   this.state.htmlContent);
     }

   const mapStateToProps = state => {
     return {
       predictions: state.Reducer.predictions,
       score: state.Reducer.score
     };
   }

   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
     return {
       fetchMyRecommendations: (Desc, userScore) => 
   dispatch(fetchRecommendations(Desc, userScore))
     };
   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
  (HomePage);
```

Ideally what I want is in the `mapStateToProps` to return the predictions array and the resp score.
I can see that they are being returned in the network call and showing up the actions call as well. Thanks in advance to whoever can help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to dispatch `getReccommendations` to actually trigger the reducer for your asynchronous action. Try the following:

```
export function fetchRecommendations (job_description, resume) {
  let url = 'myendpointurl';
  let requestPayload = {
    job_description: job_description,
    resume: resume
  };

  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios.post(url, requestPayload)
      .then(function(res) {
        dispatch(getReccommendations(res.data));
    });
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!